# jQuery - difference between '.' and '#'

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is hard to Google so I figure someone has got to ask it on here:

What is the difference between

```
 $('.sportText').text('new text added');
 $('#sportText2').text('new text added2');
```

I don't understand what the difference is between the . notation and the # notation

?

Comment: [ID selector(#)](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) - [Class selector(.)](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Comment: ID selector & class selector. Learn CSS first.

Comment: It's not jquery, it's css: 1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors 2. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Comment: It's an implementation of the W3C [*Selectors specification*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) which was intended for CSS, but has wider uses for selecting elements in general (*cf* *document.querySelector*, which implements the [*Selectors API*](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api2/)).

Comment: how hard is it to look in the API docs??

Comment: Dude. I didn't even know this was a CSS thing. I thought it was a jQuery thing. I would have spent 20 minutes looking through jQuery docs and then not known what to do next. Why didn't you read through this page before you asked a dumb question of me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **CSS-Selectors** if you specify

```
$('.sportText')
```

It will select all the elements which have **class** as `sportText`.

and when you specify

```
$('#sportText2')
```

It will select **one and only one** element which have **id** `sprtText2`.

**Because jQuery use CSS-selectors only, it works as above in JQuery as well.**

**Note:-** The id of elements should be unique, otherwise `#` selector get just first one.

**References**

[W3Schools-CSS-selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

[jQuery-basic-selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/)

Answer (score 1):

The '.' is used to select elements by class:

```
<div class="sportText">`
```

The '#' is used to select by id:

```
<div id="sportText">.
```

Answer (score 1):

`#` is selecting by id, where `.` is selecting by class.